how to search for a cell and grab the next cell data
I have 2 columns. A and B -  there is a list of project names and maybe duplicate (which is Ok) in column A. and there is a list of numbers related to that project name in column B.
I want to look for project names and grab the number next to that cell for adding up.
I have searched for different formulas, but none of them could help me.
however this one was better but not complete and working.
=SUM((FIND("projectname",A:A) "here there should be some formula to grab the next cell) and them all )
we may have 10 or 20 duplicate project names, and it's necessary to sum up all numbers next to that project.
Thanks for your time guys.

try any of these:
=FILTER(B:B; A:A="projectname")


=VLOOKUP("projectname"; A:B; 2; )


=QUERY(A:B; "select Col2 where Col1 = 'projectname'"; )

*any of these can be wrapped into SUM if needed


You may try:
=sumif(A:A,"Prject_name",B:B)

